# How to pass progress value from thread to activity?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, progressdialog, handlers

I am having a design issue sending progress bar value from class called from a Thread in Activity class to update the GUI, as the following

***[The code snippet don't compile it's for explaining only]:***

```
Class A : Extend Activity {
  new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
       public void run() 
       {
            B objB = new B();
            objB.DownloadFile();
        }
    }).start();
}

Class B {
    public void DownloadFile()
    {
       ... some work [preparing SOAP request]
       while(response.read())
       {
         //send calculated progress to Class A to update the progress value
       }

    }

}
```

Any help or guide would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an updateProgressBar method in class A and then pass class B a reference to class A. Class B could then call the callback function in A (probably pass an int or something to indicate how far the progress is). Updating the UI from a different thread then the UI thread tends to cause problems. Luckily the Activity class has the method "runOnUiThread(Runnable action)". So to set the progress you could do something like:

```
while(response.read()){
  //do stuff here
int progress = getProgress(); //set the progress to something
  a.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    a.updateProgress(progress);
  });
}
```

Comment: I am so thankful for the response i am going to test it right now and let you know the result, **thanks**.

Comment: Glad to hear it. 
The other ansewr posted by Dave might be a neater solution though. I just didn't know about the Handler Class. 
In the end I think it does roughly the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I've used a `Handler` to achieve this effect.  Create it in the `Activity` that you create the `ProgressDialog` in, then pass the `Handler` into the maethod you want to get the progress from.  Then you can send a message back to the calling `Activity` to update the progress:

```
public class ClassA extends Activity {
    ...
    private static final int HANDLER_MESSAGE_PERFORM_DIALOG_UPDATE = 0;
    ...
    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            B objB = new objB();
            objB.DownloadFile(handler);
        }
    }).start();
    ...
    private Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch(msg.what){
            case Constants.HANDLER_MESSAGE_PERFORM_DIALOG_UPDATE:
                progress.setProgress(msg.arg1);
                break;
            default:
                Log.w("TAG_NAME","handleMessage / Message type not recognised / msg.what = "+String.valueOf(msg.what));
            }
        }
    };
}

Class B 
{
    public void DownloadFile(Handler handler)
    {
       ... some work [preparing SOAP request]
       while(response.read())
       {
         //send calculated progress to Class A to update the progress value
           sendMessage(handler,HANDLER_MESSAGE_PERFORM_DIALOG_UPDATE,progress);
       }
    }
    private void sendMessage(Handler handler,int what, int arg1){
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.what = what;
        msg.arg1 = arg1;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response, i am testing this as soon as possible and see if it's more reliable than the 1st answer, thanks for both of you.

Answer (score 3):

I always use this kind of pattre and works gr8 for me...

```
class A{
    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {   
            public void run() 
            {
            B objB = new B(new ListnerClass());
            objB.DownloadFile();
            }
    }).start();

    class ListnerClass implements B.ValueListner{
        update(int v){
            doWork();
        }
    }


}

class B{

    ValueListner listner;

    interface ValuListner{
        update(int i);
    }
    B(ValueListner listner){
        this.listner = listner;
    }
    public void DownloadFile()
        {
            ... some work [preparing SOAP request]
        while(response.read())
        {
            listner.update(value);
        }

    }
}
```