# How to show progress dialog (in separate thread?) while processing some code in main thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I need to do the following: when app is started it runs an activity (splashActivity) which tries to create an DBHelper (SQLiteDatabase) instance which at creation time checks if database is exists and creates one if it doesn't.
 
In this DB creation process i want to show the ProgressDialog and *prevent the main thread to process while DB is not ready*.

the splashActivity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        showSplash();
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        dbHelper.close();
  }
}
```

the DBHelper class:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
...
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
...
  public DBHelper(Context context) { 
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    appContext=context;
    dbReadable = getReadableDatabase();
    if (createDB)
        initDB();
  } 
  @Override 
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      createDB=true;
  } 
  public void initDB() {
      ...
      if (createDB) 
          restoreDB();
      ...
  }

  private void restoreDB(){
   // place for db creation/restoring method call (restoreDBFromFile() etc)
   // and displaying the progress
  }
```

I tried to make AsyncTask as DBHelper's inner class:

```
  private class RestoreDBTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>
    {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            this.dialog = ProgressDialog.show(DBHelper.this.appContext, DBHelper.this.appContext.getResources().getString(R.string.progress_wait), 
                    DBHelper.this.appContext.getResources().getString(R.string.progress_db_installing), true);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            restoreDBFromFile();
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

so the restoreDB() was:

```
restoreDB() {
      RestoreDBTask task = new RestoreDBTask();
      task.execute();
}
```

it starts task showing PD but meanwhile the main thread continues and so it crashes cause DB wasn't ready. That means main thread should be suspended while DB is not ready so i tried to sleep/wait/join with no success. Ok. it's not good anyway.
 
Next time i made call to restoreDBFromFile() from restoreDB() so that async task was used only for PD displaying:

```
restoreDB() {
  RestoreDBTask task = new RestoreDBTask();
  task.execute();
  restoreDBFromFile();    
}
```

It doesn't display any PD. So I tried to create PD right in the restoreDB():

```
restoreDB() {
   mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(appContext, 
          appContext.getResources().getString(R.string.progress_wait), 
          appContext.getResources().getString(R.string.progress_db_installing), 
          true);
  restoreDBFromFile();    
}
```

but no PD either! Next time i tried the following:

```
    restoreDB() {
      Thread thread =  new Thread(null, new Runnable(){
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(appContext, 
                          appContext.getResources().getString(R.string.progress_wait), 
                          appContext.getResources().getString(R.string.progress_db_installing), 
                          true);
              }
          }, "ProgressDialog");
      thread.start();
      restoreDBFromFile();
}
```

once again got no PD and got immediate crash:

> 04-12 08:40:38.894:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2448): ERROR:
>   thread attach failed 04-12
>   08:40:38.913: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2448):
>   LinearAlloc 0x0 used 639500 of 5242880
>   (12%) 04-12 08:40:39.094:
>   DEBUG/ddm-heap(2454): Got feature list
>   request 04-12 08:40:39.492:
>   WARN/dalvikvm(2454): threadid=15:
>   thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x4001b188) 04-12 08:40:39.492:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2454): Uncaught
>   handler: thread ProgressDialog exiting
>   due to uncaught exception 04-12
>   08:40:39.504:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2454):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't
>   create handler inside thread that has
>   not called Looper.prepare() 04-12
>   08:40:39.504:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at
>   android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:121)
>   04-12 08:40:39.504:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at
>   android.app.Dialog.(Dialog.java:105)
>   04-12 08:40:39.504:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at
>   android.app.AlertDialog.(AlertDialog.java:63)
>   04-12 08:40:39.504:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at
>   android.app.ProgressDialog.(ProgressDialog.java:80)
>   04-12 08:40:39.504:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at
>   android.app.ProgressDialog.(ProgressDialog.java:76)
>   04-12 08:40:39.504:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at
>   android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:101)
>   04-12 08:40:39.504:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at
>   android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
>   04-12 08:40:39.504:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at
>   com.taxiorder.DBHelper$1.run(DBHelper.java:157)
>   04-12 08:40:39.504:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

.
Tried a few more things with no result... So I just can't figure out what's wrong.

Once again - I just need to show PD while restoreDB() executing. I can't run restoreDB() in separate thread because I need it finished before app can proceed. As I can see PD should be run in separate thread only but i can't manage it.
Now I have 2 additional questions:

1) If a PD should be created in separate thread could it be created and showed if it's thread doesn't do anything at all. I mean something like this:

```
    new Thread(){
          public void run(){
              mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(appContext, 
                      appContext.getResources().getString(R.string.progress_wait), 
                      appContext.getResources().getString(R.string.progress_db_installing), 
                      true);

      }.start();
```

As I understand the thread dies immediately after executing run() cause there is nothing to do and so PD doesn't show.
2) PD by itself doesn't suspend any thread while displaying, does it?

Comment: Man that's too much code to follow :) , i hope this will help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930971/android-how-to-pass-progress-bar-value-from-thread-to-the-activity)

Comment: I'm not clear on your `Activity` setup, do you have a main `Activity` that is calling your `SplashActivity`, or is `SplashActivity` the first one to be run?  Where is the code you refer to as: "...prevent the main thread..."?

Comment: SplashActivity is the main Activity.

Comment: and where is the code you refer to as: "...prevent the main thread..."?

Comment: if i make restoreDB() in separate thread it will run created by DBHelper and the same time SplashActivity ends and the next activity starts where listview should be populated from DB which wouldn't be ready. So by "prevent the main thread" I meant to prevent SplashActivity end by preventing return from DBHelper before DB was restored.

Comment: the meain thread I mean is the thread which enters SplashActivity and than follows to the DBHelper's restoreDB() method. I need to freeze it until the DB wouldn't be restored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to declare `AsyncTask` as an inner class for the activity, instantiate and execute it there. I think the problem is in context given to `ProgressDialog` when you are creating it, your logic for doing this is too complicated. Declaring `AsyncTask` in activity is more common practice.

Then, AsyncTask must do all you need with DB in `doInBackground` method

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        new RestoreDBTask().execute();
    }

}

private class RestoreDBTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>
{
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(
            SplashActivity.this,
            getString(R.string.progress_wait),
            getString(R.string.progress_db_installing), 
            true);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        // do all the things with DB
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(SplashActivity.this);
        dbHelper.close();
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: The main point I don't like it is that I dont't have to create PB always but just in case of the app's first run which determined in DBHelper.<br>
IMHO it shouldn't be a code in Activity at least I don't want it there.

Comment: Oh... i see your point. Try to refactor my code sample bit later.

Comment: I already have class like yours in DBHelper but like I said while it executes the SplashActivity continues its execution at the same time. It have to be something about sychronized() i guess.

Comment: Did refactoring by myself. Works good now. The main point i got is  PD can't be managed from any class but directly from Activity only. It's bad and stupid but as far as can see it is so.

Comment: I think the reason of that - UI thread. Some database helper's methods might work not on UI thread and thus PB is not normally accessible here. Also, the Thread you are creating by yourself also NOT an UI thread.

Comment: So it's all about UI thread... Sure SQLiteOpenHelper doesn't need any.